# NSUserDefault doubts in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

i have a text held in my main view and a button next to textiew ,when i click the button it popup a popoverviewcontroler,in my popover controller view there is some text,in a tableview(high,low,medium,flair)i want when the user tap the high it needs to lot in the main textfield,but i tried nsuserdefault in the DiSelect row at index path.but nothing happen when i click the tableiew.how can i do this.
my code

```
NSString *strr = @"High";//i put the static value 


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strr forKey:@"flair"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

this code is in popoveriewconteroler
and in my main view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSString *strr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"flair"];
    textfiled.text = strr;
}
```

when i go back to another page and comes back it lodes the high in the text filed.but i my red is when the user tap the popoveriewcontroller  tableviewcell,it changes the text filed value at the same time.is this possible.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand that english is not your first language, but could you try to make the question more clear? I have no idea what your problem is. Also - use a spellchecker, there are *so* many typos in your post.

Comment: Peter Sarnowski haii,english s not my first language ,but objectivc c is my programming language,i need to get the value from popoveriewcontroller tableiew to main view text filed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you want to update the text label when user tap on a table cell?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strr forKey:@"flair"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    textfiled.text = strr;
}
```

---

not sure what your asking

but you can have a property for your popover controller

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyMainViewController *mainViewController;
```

and a property for your main view controller

```
@property (nonoatomic, retain) UITextField *textField;
```

than in the place you create the popover controller

```
MyPopoverController *popoverController = // create popover controller
popoverController.mainViewController = // mainViewController
```

than you can replace

```
 textfiled.text = strr;
```

to

```
self.mainViewController.textField.text = strr;
```

Comment: haii,but this textfiled is in  main view

Comment: than you need somehow get access to that text field in your popover controller. for example pass the view controller to the popover controller and have a property for the text field

Comment: ye you re correct,but how to navigate a popover controller to main view

Comment: when  tied to pass the value through push another popovercontroler with main view comes.